# Deleted Kafka topic can't be recreated with the same name

Tags: apache-kafka

I marked a topic for deletion and it sat there forever not deleting (even though delete.topic.enable is set to true). So I followed the instructions and shelled into one of the zookeepers and ran the following to get it deleted:

```
rmr /brokers/topics/topicname
rmr /admin/delete_topics/topicname
```

The topic then appeared to be deleted (would not come back on a list command). But then when I tried to recreate it with new configuration (compaction turned on), the in-sync-replicas are empty and I can't consume from the topic. Consumption comes back with 'UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION' errors even though the list command shows the topic as being there.

Is there a log somewhere I can look at to see why it is not able to get the topic setup properly after deletion and recreation? Am I missing a step and not properly deleting the topic to begin with? Why is the recreated topic not getting properly initialized?

What I ran to delete the topic initially before running the two commands above (this left the topic in 'marked for deletion' for a long time):

```
./kafka-topics.sh  --zookeeper $KAFKAZKHOSTS --delete --topic topicname
```

What I ran to recreate the topic:

```
/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper $KAFKAZKHOSTS --replication-factor 3 --partitions 3 --topic topicname --config cleanup.policy=compact
```

Kafka version: **1.1.0.2.6.5.3005-27**

Comment: How did you produce messages to the topic?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Just with the regular producer client for java.

Comment: Can you provide the actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I read somewhere that you should restart the brokers and that may solve it. So I tried that and sure enough after the restart the ISRs are in the right state and the topic is consumable again.

I would still like to know under what circumstances this can happen and if there's a way to fix it without restarting brokers since in a production environment I would like to avoid doing that.

Comment: I have seen similar behavior but am not sure exactly the circumstances when it will happen. I've seen it in Kafka 1.1.0 but not (yet?) in 1.1.1